# Image quality reduces (turns reddish) as JPEG with BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, image-processing, jpeg

I am making a program where I extract out pixel array from an image, Take out ARGB values. And write them back again to make another image.

```
        BufferedImage imagebuffer = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Ramandeep\\Downloads\\w3.jpg"));
        iw = imagebuffer.getWidth();
        ih = imagebuffer.getHeight();
       
        pixels = new int[iw * ih];
        PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(imagebuffer, 0, 0, iw, ih, pixels, 0, iw);
        pg.grabPixels();  
    
      BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      image.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
        

        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\Ramandeep\\Desktop\\out.jpg"));
        ImageIO.write(image, "gif", new File("C:\\Users\\Ramandeep\\Desktop\\out.gif"));
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\Ramandeep\\Desktop\\out.png"));
```

Now output image for png and gif look fine but the output jpg image turns out quite reddish.

This is the original image
[image]
And this is the output jpg image
[image]

Any idea what might be causing this? Any push towards the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Whats the image processing your attempt should reach ?

Comment: Well,I am working towards embedding a plain text message inside the image using LSB substitution method. But before that I am just trying out simply writing the pixels as it is in a new image to get that out of the way.

Comment: why dont use Graphics ?

Comment: umm. I guess , I wasn't aware of that class. Does it have proper methods to fetch pixel array and vice versa? 
Can you point me to a working example somewhere? That would be great. Or I'll grind through the documentation xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this will work for you, but I always did it pixel-by-pixel.
So :

```
BufferedImage imagebuffer = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Ramandeep\\Downloads\\w3.jpg"));
iw = imagebuffer.getWidth();
ih = imagebuffer.getHeight();
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(iw,ih,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
for (int x=0; x < iw; x++) {
     for (int y=0; y < ih; y++) {
          image.setRGB(x,y,imagebuffer.getRGB(x,y));
     }
}
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\Ramandeep\\Desktop\\out.jpg"));
ImageIO.write(image, "gif", new File("C:\\Users\\Ramandeep\\Desktop\\out.gif"));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\Ramandeep\\Desktop\\out.png"));
```

And it this way has a similar count of lines, so I think you could give it a try.

If you'd like to insert text, id `ìmport java.awt.*;`, what includes Graphics and Graphics2D and Font, and then :

```
Font font=new Font("Sans,0,20); //Name, type(none, bold, italic), size
Graphics2D imagegraphics=imagebuffer.createGraphics();
imagegraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); //enable antialiasing
imagegraphics.setFont(font);
imagegraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
String yourtext="Fighter";
int h=imagegraphics.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
int w=imagegraphics.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(yourtext);
imagegraphics.drawString(yourtext,5,h); //Draw text upper left corner, note that y-value is the bottom line of the string
```

**EDIT :**

It was the Alpha value. Fixed by :

```
BufferedImage image = new
BufferedImage(iw,ih,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); //RGB, jpeg hasnt got alpha, ints have been converted as if they contain red first, but its alpha(the first bytes, these ints are interpreted bitwise i think) (argb), so it became more red.
```

Comment: Let me give this a whirl and get back.

Comment: Ah.. Unfortunately, same result.  jpg has a reddish tint.

Comment: @Ramandeep : Please have a look at -my edit about how to insert text -try `jpeg` probably instead of `jpg`

Comment: I think you misunderstood me a little. I don't want to draw text on top of the image. 
I am implementing steganography using LSB substitution method to hide text in rgb bits of pixels.

Comment: @Ramandeep : You mean something like a watermark ? Or do you want to hide some data ?

Comment: Well, Not really. 
You can still see watermarks. 
In this case, output image looks exactly the same. 
We are hiding data inside the image so it becomes invisible to the eye. 
It's a sister branch of cryptography. Look up steganography, You'll get what I am saying.

Comment: @Ramandeep : But how can you hide data without changing the pixels colors, what would make it visible ? Are you generating a int from the char ? And then splitting up the int using some methods into for example four ints and then you add them to the pixels int using setRGB, if it gets over maximum int subtract ? And then using comparison to original you can extract it again?

Comment: Well, We write only the least significant bits of the colors so the color values changes very slighly. like from rgb (240,230,56) to rgb (230,213,71)
You can check this for further info on the subject
http://isrc.ccs.asia.edu.tw/yourslides/files/68/Hiding%20data%20in%20images%20by%20simple%20LSB%20substitution.pdf


In any case, that's the easy part, I am just stuck at the writing "pixels to a jpeg image" part.

Comment: @Ramandeep : Probably you are using the wrong image viewer ? Im having an Ubuntu and when looking at the images, my default image viewer shows wrong colors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142160/discussion-between-ramandeep-and-user7185318).

Comment: Yes, Changing the type to TYPE_INT_RGB worked. Thanks.